# Tomcat 10 Port 8443 (SSL) not working on local/external IP address but working on localhost

Tags: ssl, tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat10

I have been trying to configure Tomcat 10.0.4 alongside IntelliJ Idea for my Java Web project. However, I am unable to run the project using SSL on port 8443. I have also included the Tomcat Native Library dll in the tomcat bin folder. Under build configuration settings in IntelliJ, I have also included the port number for HTTPS.

Upon building and running the server, https://localhost:8443 works as expected. However, when I try to access the web server using the local ip address (192.168.1.2) or through my external IP address, chrome spits `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Port 80 works perfectly fine through both means.

I have port forwarding enabled for the ports 80, 443 and 8443 (which works considering Port 80 works fine) but 8443 does not work. On Windows 10, I have also allowed inbound and outbound connection to 8443 in firewall settings.

The following is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
 <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" useAprConnector="true" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
                redirectPort="8443"
                useIPVHosts="true" 
                address="0.0.0.0"/>
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
               secure="true" SSLEngine="true" scheme="https"  clientAuth="false"
               sslProtocol="TLS">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
                <Certificate             
                        certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey1.pem"
                        certificateFile="conf/cert1.pem"
                        certificateChainFile="conf/chain1.pem"
                type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" 
               resolveHosts="true"/>

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Update (04/24/2021 @ 5:07 PM**
The following is log messages upon startup:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.698 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Listener] failed to set property [useAprConnector] to [true]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.811 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector] failed to set property [SSLEngine] to [true]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.811 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector] failed to set property [clientAuth] to [false]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.812 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Connector] failed to set property [sslProtocol] to [TLS]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.868 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Server/Service/Engine/Host/Valve] failed to set property [resolveHosts] to [true]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.4
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 5 2021 11:07:15 UTC
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.4.0
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.10+8-LTS-162
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\MicroTechTon\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\tomcat\6454be16-6e63-47f0-9175-b6e43d48845f
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\MicroTechTon\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\tomcat\6454be16-6e63-47f0-9175-b6e43d48845f\conf\logging.properties
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=C:\Users\MicroTechTon\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\tomcat\6454be16-6e63-47f0-9175-b6e43d48845f\jmxremote.password
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=C:\Users\MicroTechTon\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\tomcat\6454be16-6e63-47f0-9175-b6e43d48845f\jmxremote.access
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\MicroTechTon\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1\tomcat\6454be16-6e63-47f0-9175-b6e43d48845f
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\temp
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.879 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.28] using APR version [1.7.0].
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
24-Apr-2021 17:00:26.884 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.200 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-80"]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.228 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-apr-8443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.228 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [783] milliseconds
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.4]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.428 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-80"]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.449 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
24-Apr-2021 17:00:27.457 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [117] milliseconds
Connected to server
```

Comment: You need to look into the logs (`catalina.<date>.log`) whether the connector failed to start and add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I was only able to find cataline.<date>.log for an old date in  tomcat/logs. I have updated the post to reflect the startup stdout log lines.